# How to solve 3rd order Ordinary Differential Equation by using Wronskian?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The ODE is  $$ (D^3-6D^2+11D-6)y=e^{2x}$$
I know how to solve $2$nd order. But, I don't know the formula for $3$rd order.
let the complementary function be
$$y=c_1f_1+c_2f_2+c_3f_3$$
let the particular integral be 
$$y=c_1(x)f_1+c_2(x)f_2+c_3(x)f_3$$
After solving the $3$ degree matrix I get the value of $W(f_1,f_2,f_3)$
But what to do next ? What is the formula to find   the value of $c_1(x),c_2(x),c_3(x)$

Comment: It's better to add the DE in your question

Comment: Ok, I am adding it.

Comment: If you mean you already solved the homogeneous equation for solution $f1,f2,f2$, then just apply variation of parameter to solve for $c1,c2,c3$. If you haven't solved it, but only get the Wronskian, then it's not possible to obtain the solution from just knowing the Wronskian.

Comment: I hope that you meant $e^{2x}$ on the RHS

Comment: @calcstudent I know how to solve 2nd order in Wronskian. The issue is the formula that I don't know for order 3.

Comment: Inverse the wronskian matrix and integrate.

Comment: @RajatDash: when you say Wronskian do you mean the matrix or the determinant? If you have the matrix, then it's variation of parameter, the same as 2nd order. If you only solved for the determinant, then it's not enough to find the solutions.

Comment: @calcstudent no, I mean matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean method of variation of parameters for a third Order Differential Equation. And you already have solved the homogeneous equation.

It's $$\pmatrix { c'_1 \\ c'_2 \\c'_3}=W^{-1}\pmatrix { 0 \\ 0 \\e^{2x} }$$
Where $W^{-1}$ is the inverse of Wronskian matrix  and $c_i'$ are derivatives.

---

**Edit** I added some calculations

$$W=\pmatrix {e^x & e^{2x} &e^{3x} \\ e^x & 2e^{2x} & 3e^{3x} \\ e^x & 4e^{2x} & 9e^{3x}}$$
it's easy to find the determinant $|W|=2e^{6x}$
Now you need the inverse of the Wronskian Matrix ...We don't need all the elements of the matrix. Only the last column is needed:
$$W^{-1}=\frac 1 {|W|}\pmatrix {* & * &e^{5x} \\ * & *& -2e^{4x} \\ * & * & e^{3x}}$$
So we have that:
$$\pmatrix { c'_1 \\ c'_2 \\c'_3}=\frac 1 {|W|}\pmatrix {* & * &e^{5x} \\ * & *& -2e^{4x} \\ * & * & e^{3x}}\pmatrix { 0 \\ 0 \\e^{2x} }$$
$$\pmatrix { c'_1 \\ c'_2 \\c'_3}=\frac 1 {|W|}\pmatrix { e^{7x}\\ -2e^{6x} \\e^{5x} }$$
$$\pmatrix { c'_1 \\ c'_2 \\c'_3}=\frac 1 {2}\pmatrix { e^{x}\\ -2 \\e^{-x} }$$
Now integrate to find the $c_i$ coefficients:
$$\pmatrix { c_1 \\ c_2 \\c_3}=\pmatrix { \frac 1 {2}e^{x}\\ -x \\-\frac 1 {2}e^{-x} }$$
The particular solution is therefore:
$$y_p=c_1e^x+c_2e^{2x}+c_3e^{3x}$$
$$y_p=\frac 1 {2}e^{2x}-xe^{2x}-\frac 1 {2}e^{2x}$$
$$y_p=-xe^{2x}$$

Variation of Constants is a much better method for your differential equation. Your guess should be: $$y_p=Axe^{2x}$$

Comment: @RajatDash   You already have the Wronskian Rajat ? Just calculate the inverser and integrate to get the coefficients $c_i$

Comment: Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @RajatDashyw Rajat I added a complte solution..I hope it's more clear now. I suppose that you have already calculated the Wronskian Matrix. So I take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

$$(D^3-6D^2+11D-6)y=e^{2x}\tag1$$
Auxiliary equation is $~m^3-6m^2+11m-6=0\implies (m-1)(m-2)(m-3)=0$.

Roots of the auxiliary equation is $~m=1,~2,~3~.$

So complementary function (C.F.)$~~~=c_1 ~e^x~+~c_2~e^{2x}~+~c_3~e^{3x}~$, where $~c_1,~c_2,~c_3~$are constants.

Here $~f(D)=D^3-6D^2+11D-6~$.

Clearly, $~f(2)=0~$but$~f'(2)=-1\ne 0~$.

So particular integral (P.I.),

P.I.$~~=\dfrac{1}{D^3-6D^2+11D-6}~e^{2x}$

$~~~~~~~=x~\dfrac{e^{2x}}{-1}~~~~~($ by rule $2~)$

$~~~~~~~=-~x~e^{2x}$

So the general solution of the differential equation $(1)$ is
$$y(x)=~\text{C.F.}~+~\text{P.I.}$$
$$\implies y(x)=c_1 ~e^x~+~c_2~e^{2x}~+~c_3~e^{3x}~-~x~e^{2x}$$
where $~c_1,~c_2,~c_3~$are constants.

---

> Consider a differential equation of the form $f(D)y=X$
>
> If $X=e^{ax}$, then
>
> $1.$ P.I.$\quad = \frac{1}{f(D)}e^{ax}=\frac{e^{ax}}{f(a)}$, if $f(a)\neq 0$
>
> $2.$ P.I.$\quad =\frac{1}{f(D)}e^{ax}=x~\frac{e^{ax}}{f'(a)}$, if $~f(a)=0~$but$~f'(a)\ne 0$
>
> $3.$ P.I.$\quad =\frac{1}{f(D)}e^{ax}=x^2~\frac{e^{ax}}{f''(a)}$, if $~f(a)=0,~f'(a)= 0~$but$~f''(a)\ne 0$
>
> and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for variation of parameter is the same regardless of order. This is because they all come from writing the equation as a first order vector-valued ODE, by making vector of the form $(f(x),f^{\prime}(x),...,f^{(n)}(x))^{t}$

For any first order vector-valued homogeneous ODE: $v^{\prime}(x)=A(x)v(x)$ where $A$ is a square $n\times n$ matrix, then the Wronskian matrix is a square matrix solution that is non-singular at one point: some square $W(x)$ such that $W^{\prime}(x)=A(x)v(x)$.

Assuming you solved $W$, the inhomogeneous version can be solved by variation of parameter. We have the inhomogeneous equation $v^{\prime}(x)-A(x)v(x)=b(x)$. Writing $D$ for $\frac{d}{dx}$ and writing the equation without the argument $(x)$ then this become $Dv-Av=b$. Since $Dv-Av=D(WW^{-1}v)-A(WW^{-1}v)=(DW)(W^{-1}v))+WD(W^{-1}v)-(AW)(W^{-1}v)=(DW-AW)(W^{-1}v)+WD(W^{-1}v)$. Making use of the definition of $W$ then $DW-AW=0$ so $WD(W^{-1}v)=b$ so $D(W^{-1}v)=W^{-1}b$. This is the formula for variation of parameter.